# Putting an aspx website within another aspx website's root directory

Tags: asp.net, web

I have translated a company's website to English, the aspx webpages have a masterpage.

So, the structure is like this

`Server/Website's Root Folder/`   ---> This directory has the webpages in their native language.

Server/Website's Root Folder/en/ ---> This directory has the webpages in the english language. Also renamed the `company.master` to `company_en.master` and changed the references to the masterpage.

Now, when I type the url `www.company.com` it runs fine.

Once ı try to access `www.company.com/en` I get a runtime error saying;

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

Is it possible to do this or should I get a new domain name?

Comment: You got a server error, but you didn't tell us what the server error is and it sounds like you didn't try to debug it. You need to figure out what the underlying error is.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) this is what it says on the console. However the files are already under the server, within the  `en/` folder

Comment: What is an example of the URL that you are accessing, and what is an example of the corresponding directory structure?

Comment: Did you move the master page? Are links relative or absolute? Might need to change some paths to ../ if you moved things into a subdirectory.

Comment: Directories are the same, I copied the whole folder first, did the translation, renamed it to en and put it to the root as a folder. The links are at the top of the pages, like this `<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/company.master" AutoEventWireup="true"` I renamed all the links in the en folder to `MasterPageFile="~/company_en.master" ` and put that master to `en/` directory as well